# Load Binary file in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, flatbuffers

I am working in Angular 5 to integrate flatbuffers response with my API call.
I am trying to load binary file using HttpClient in Angular 5.

I have tried below code to get byte data in Uint8Array. Also tried with Blob but its not working.

```
let apiUrl = "./assets/test.bin";
const headers = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({responseType: "application/octet-stream"})
};

let data : Observable<Uint8Array> = this.http.get<Uint8Array>(apiUrl, headers);
data.subscribe( (response: Uint8Array) => {
  const data = response;
  // console.log(data); 
  console.log("successful");

  return data;
}, (error : HttpErrorResponse)=> {
  console.log(error.error.text);      
});
```

[Binary file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N2QpJ5RNPNAVb_r869GG29JhqrZXqJWA/view)

[FBS Generated TS file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Krr37QoFIJgmoKkfJxDA9AoODYwH8Jra/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
let apiUrl = "./assets/test.bin";
const headers = {responseType: "blob"};

let data : Observable<Blob> = this.http.get<Blob>(apiUrl, headers);
data.subscribe( (response: Blob) => {
  const data = response;
  console.log(data); 
}, (error : HttpErrorResponse)=> {
  console.log(error.error.text);      
});
```

Comment: Tried but not working.. Got this error: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4201/assets/test.bin".

Comment: Agreed same problem here. This is trying to parse it as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @sabithpocker would work if the header object was right. Because of the wrong header the angular http module parses it as an json. The correct header would look like:

```
const headers = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
     'Accept':'blob'
  }),
  'responseType': 'blob' as 'json'
 }
```